# Solving for $x$ of different powers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to solve the following equation for $x$

$$\left(x + \frac{6}{x} \right)^2 + \left( x + \frac{6}{x} \right) = 30$$

I done my working till -

$$x^4 + x^3 - 18x^2 + 6x + 36 = 0$$

From here how do I solve for $x$ when I have any different powers ?

Comment: Why not start with $y=x+{6\over x}$ and solve for $y$ first?

Comment: Or factor the equation you end up with $(x-3)(x-2)(x^2+6x+6)$.

Comment: Note that the equation you started with has a nice structure. The "simplified" quartic, not so much.

Answer (score 8):

Hint: set $$t=x+\frac{6}{x}$$ and you will get a quadratic equation in $t$

Answer (score 0):

$t^2+t=30$ iff $t=5$ or $t=-6$, and 
$$ x+\frac{6}{x}\in\{-6,5\} $$
iff $\color{red}{x\in\{2,3,-3-\sqrt{3},-3+\sqrt{3}\}}$.